# Changing Basis question: how is this the right answer?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

First part is fine, I get 2/5 but how is the instructor getting 11/5 and not 55/7?

[Formula being used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpKOe.png):

[image]

[Changing Basis Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzd5y.png):
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer indicated is correct, because $\dfrac25\pmatrix{3\\4}+\dfrac{11}5\pmatrix{4\\-3}=\pmatrix{10\\-5}$.

You should divide by the square of the magnitude of the basis vector,

which is $(4)^2+(-3)^2=25$, not $(4)^2-(3)^2=7$.